# HP Laserjet 200 prints Grey scale only

Tags: printer, troubleshooting, hp-laserjet

I have an HP Laserjet 200 colorMFP M276nw printer that only prints in grey scale. Even stuff like the supplies status report prints in grey scale, and the bar for yellow is really light, and cyan is medium grey, so I think they are supposed to print in color. The supplies status report says that all the color is 50%-60% and the black cartridge is empty. The black still prints fine. It's been this way for a couple weeks now.

The *question* is "what might be the problem and what should I do to try to fix it?"

Here is a scan of the supplies status page. Notice how the title and the level bars are difference shades of grey.

[image: Scanned supplies status page]

Comment: Great story, not much of a question. :)  Does it print it's self-test pages in color?  Have you checked the driver setting in your OS to ensure you haven't forced it into Monochrome or Greyscale mode?  In trying to fix it, what have you tried already?

Comment: Yes, the supplies status report prints in grey-scale, but it appears like it should print in color.

Comment: Is this a brand new printer, that you just unpacked from the box?

Comment: Have you tried all the things on this page? - [HP Customer Support, Troubleshooting Print Quality Issues](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03416215&tmp_task=solveCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5097654)

Comment: We got it in February or March, 2013.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I had the same problem. user453303 gave the correct answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As the test page is also in grey, the problem is in the printer itself. There are 2 things I would try.

First, check that the printer itself is not set to print greyscale only. I know the driver should override that setting, but check it anyway. I have not been able to find a manual that explains how to, but, if it's there, you should be able to find it under the Setup button on the control panel.

If that does not help, I would reset the printer to factory defaults, as follows (from the [User's Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02851622.pdf), pg 150):

1. From the Home screen on the printer's control panel, touch the Setup button.
2. Scroll to and touch the Service menu.
3. Scroll to and touch the Restore Defaults button, and then touch the OK button.
   The product automatically restarts

Note that this will clear all settings you may have in the printer, including things like IP the address.

If that still does not solve it, call HP to fix it under warranty.

Answer (score 1):

In system setup, supply settings, select color and Very Low setting.  This is where it's "hidden" that when you color toner gets low the printer will print in black/grayscale.  Select Continue and the printer will continue printing in color until the toner is actually gone.

Answer (score 0):

When one of the color cartridges is low, the screen will ask if you want to continue in color (poor quality) or in black/white. If you select black/white, you're kinda stuck in that mode. I couldn't find a way to reset it, so I reset the printer back to factory defaults. It was faster that way.